# (Flutter/Dart) Replace all parentheses with html tags parentheses in string?

Tags: string, mobile, dart, flutter

I need to replace parentheses that is using some special character with html tags.

Example:

"''test''" become "< b >test< /b >"

"//Example//" become "< i >Example< /i >"

How to achieve this using Dart language in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replaceFirst` could make you want.

```
main() {
  String test = "\"test\" //Example//";

  final Map<String, List<String>> map = {
    "\"": ["< b >", "< \/b >"],
    "//": ["< i >", "< /i >"]
  };

  map.forEach((key, mapping) {
    test = test.replaceFirst(key, mapping[0]);
    test = test.replaceFirst(key, mapping[1]);
  });

  print(test);
}
```